# self join multiple accounts same id

Tags: self-join

I am still learning how to use self-joins.

I would like to find out if somebody has multiple accounts by querying the same id. 
My understanding of self join is the following:

```
select, 
a.account_number, 
a.person_id, 
b.person_id 
from table a
inner join table b
on a.person_id = b.person_id
```

But it is bringing back the person_id twice but not showing me if there are different accounts.

Can I have some guidance please?

Many Thanks, 
JB

Comment: you need to use `distinct`

Comment: Thank you Lucumt. I have added distinct by select distinct person_id

Comment: distinct has worked, thanks again :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37384306/3404097