# SQL Self Join: Why is the right half of the table different than the left half?

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.num, a.company, a.stop,stopa.id id1, stopa.name Aname, b.num bnum,b.company bcompany ,stopb.name Bname, b.stop ,stopb.id id2
FROM route a
JOIN route b ON (a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num)
JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop = stopa.id)
JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop = stopb.id)
```

[image: SQL Output]

[image: Basic table diagram]

**The original problem:**

> **Using self-joins**, find the routes involving two buses that can go from Craiglockhart to Lochend.
> Show the bus no. and company for the first bus, the name of the stop for the transfer,
> and the bus no. and company for the second bus.

I know that the solution is to create two tables using subqueries and then to JOIN those two together where stopids are equal.  However, I don't understand *why* it works the way it does.

Very new to SQL and trying to understand what's going on here.
I honestly need as detailed of a breakdown as you can provide.

What purpose does the **route** self join serve here?  If **stopa** is the same as **stopb** and each is being matched to routea and routeb, why are they different in the table?

I would appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Comment: *why are they different in the table?* Because the columns pair values mentioned in joining expression are not unique. Check - in any row the eqiality for `company=bcompany` and `num=bnum` is observed - everything according to the condition. But joining condition does not require for another columns equiality.

Comment: *I don't understand.* Imagine that you have 2 rows of 2 columns with the values (1,1) and (1,2). You join by 1st column - and obtain 4 rows (1,1,1,1), (1,1,1,2), (1,2,1,1) and (1,2,1,2). 1st column = 3rd column - like you have asked. But 2nd and 4th columns may differ - you do not ask them to be equal too.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your kindness and patience.  What I wasn't understanding was that a self join is functionally a table with an inner join on itself and that the result is a Cartesian product.  It was explained to me by a trainer at work that the table is 1:1, not a Cartesian product.  And for some reason, this was not mentioned in any of the tutorials I completed.  Anyway, thank you again.  I hope you are well.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS Please clarify via edits & not comments. PS If you have an answer consider posting one. Comments are not for answers. PS [What is a self join for? (in english)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37384306/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

The self-join is needed so you can relate different stops on a route (which is what your query does) or relate different routes to each other. If you don't join, you just get one stop at a time, you're not pairing up anything.

BTW, you don't need subqueries to solve your problem. You can use a query similar to the one you have, but use a different `ON` condition to relate the routes. Then you'll need `WHERE` conditions to specify that one of the routes stops at `Craiglockhart` while the other stops at `Lochhend`. You'll need a third `JOIN` with `stops` to get the name of the transfer stop.