# Mysql query to get user's specific status record based on it's time priority ( if specific status processed last/ recent)

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have user_status table it consist of different users  and their status( A,B,C,D) now my requirement is status A should get compare with all other status(B,C,D) and get only record of status A value  if status A updated time is greater then all other status but status A is processed before (B,C,D) so updated time is less compare to other status then in this scenario don't get any record

```
id  user_id  status         updated

1       1       C       2023-12-28 23:32:06
2       1       B       2023-12-28 23:34:06
3       1       A       2023-12-28 23:36:06

4       2       B       2023-12-27 23:12:02   
5       2       D       2023-12-27 23:15:08
6       2       A       2023-12-27 23:18:06
7       2       C       2023-12-27 23:22:06
```

**Expected output :**
id=3
For user-1 record should get=>  for this user recent status is A and B,C,D processed before A so priority is given to Status A

For user-2 no record should get because status A must processed last  however it got already processed and hence last  status for this user is C

```
Mysql query :

SELECT t1.* 
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 on t2.status=t1.status where t1.status='A' and t1.updated > t2.updated
```

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my reading of your question, it seems that for each `user_id` value you want to compare the `updated` value for the row with `status` = 'A' with the `updated` value for the rows with `status` <> `A` and select the `A` row if its `updated` value is greater than the `updated` value for the other rows. If so, then the following should work.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE user_status (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  status CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  updated DATETIME NOT NULL
  );
  
INSERT INTO user_status VALUES
  (1, 1, 'C', '2023-12-28 23:32:06'),
  (2, 1, 'B', '2023-12-28 23:34:06'),
  (3, 1, 'A', '2023-12-28 23:36:06'),
  (4, 2, 'B', '2023-12-27 23:12:02'),
  (5, 2, 'D', '2023-12-27 23:15:08'),
  (6, 2, 'A', '2023-12-27 23:18:06'),
  (7, 2, 'C', '2023-12-27 23:22:06')
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT u.* FROM user_status u JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(updated) AS max_updated FROM user_status
    WHERE status <> 'A'
    GROUP BY user_id
) sq ON u.user_id = sq.user_id AND u.status = 'A' AND u.updated > sq.max_updated
;
```

| id | user_id | status | updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | A | 2023-12-28 23:36:06 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pcVkqYNkDfu5eTs8SGNkrP/0)

**Note**

The join condition `... AND u.status = 'A' ...` is not really necessary since given that `u.updated > sq.max_updated`, then the `status` column value must be 'A'. So we really only need:

```mysql
SELECT u.* FROM user_status u JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(updated) AS max_updated FROM user_status
    WHERE status <> 'A'
    GROUP BY user_id
) sq ON u.user_id = sq.user_id AND u.updated > sq.max_updated
;
```

But if we changed the condition `u.updated > sq.max_updated` to `u.updated >= sq.max_updated`, then we would have to add the additional test `u.status = 'A'` because there will always be at least one non-'A' row for which `u.updated >= sq.max_updated`.

**Further Explantion**

Consider the following subquery (you can refer to the [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pcVkqYNkDfu5eTs8SGNkrP/1), which I have updated to show what the subquery yields):

```mysql
SELECT user_id, MAX(updated) AS max_updated FROM user_status
WHERE status <> 'A'
GROUP BY user_id
```

This creates one row for each unique `user_id` with two columns, the `user_id` and `max_updated`, which is the greatest value of the `updated` column for that `user_id` considering only rows whose `user_status` is not 'A':

| user_id | max_updated |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-12-28 23:34:06 |
| 2 | 2023-12-27 23:22:06 |

Then for a given `user_id` if there is a corresponding `user_status` row with `status` = 'A' that has an `updated` column greater than this subquery's `max_updated` value, then we then wish to select that row. We can determine such rows by joining the `user_status` table with the above subquery using the appropriate join conditions. Note that this is not a self join, which is when you join a table with itself. In this case we are joining the `user_status` table with a subquery that is based on the `user_status` table but which is not the `user_status` table itself.

Comment: @MSP Please ask another (specifiic researched non-duplicate) question in another question post. PS The same table is used twice because 1st we get `max_updated FROM user_status` then we find matches in the original table. It's technically only a self-join in expressed in certain ways. [What is a self join for? (in english)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37384306/3404097)  [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Comment: I have updated the question with a **Further Explanation**. I don't know if this answers all of your questions.