# SQL: Returning a list of all the classes that 2 specific students are both attending

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, relational-database

I've tried all I can to figure this one out, hopefully someone here can help.

I'm given the database schema as follows:

> Customer:  ID  FirstName   LastName    DateOfBirth
>
> Instructor: Id FirstName   LastName
>
> FitnessClass: Id   ClassName   Cost    InstructorId
>
> Subscription: CustomerId   ClassId StartDate

With the question being:

> Retrieve a list of all classes (Id and ClassName) that both Joe Bloggs and John Snow have subscribed to (ie Joe Bloggs and John Snow have been in the same Fitness Class).

My attempts have only produced all classes that either are in, not only the classes that both are in.

My attempt:

```
SELECT fitnessclass.id, fitnessclass.classname
FROM fitnessclass
LEFT JOIN subscription ON fitnessclass.Id = subscription.ClassID
LEFT JOIN customer ON subscription.CustomerID = customer.ID
WHERE customer.ID IS NOT NULL
AND customer.FirstName IN ("Joe", "Bloggs")
```

Comment: Please read about [ask] and [mcve]s.

Comment: What exactly have you tried in the WHERE? Because 'Bloggs' is not a first name.

Comment: Was originally 'John' instead of 'Bloggs', just a transcribing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want the `c.ClassId` and `c.ClassName` values from `DISTINCT` rows where:

```
    class c.Id is named c.ClassName and costs c.Cost and is taught by c.InstructorId
AND customer c1.ID is named c1.FirstName c1.LastName and was born on c1.DateOfBirth
AND customer c2.ID is named c2.FirstName c2.LastName and was born on c2.DateOfBirth
AND c1.ID <> c2.ID
AND customer s1.CustomerId subscribed to s1.ClassId starting on s1.StartDate
AND customer s2.CustomerId subscribed to s2.ClassId starting on s2.StartDate
AND c1.ID = s1.CustomerId AND c2.ID = s2.CustomerId
AND c1.FirstName = 'Joe' AND c1.LastName = 'Bloggs'
AND c2.FirstName = 'John' AND c2.LastName = 'Snow'
AND s1.ClassId = c.ClassId AND s2.ClassId = c.ClassId
```

Observe that an aliased table with no duplicates holds (the set of) rows that make a true statement from a statement template (*predicate*) associated with its base table by the database designer:

```
--  class c.Id is named c.ClassName and costs c.Cost and is taught by c.instructorId
FitnessClass c

-- cx.ID is named cx.FirstName cx.LastName and was born on cx.DateOfBirth
Customer cx

-- customer sx.CustomerId subscribed to class sx.ClassId starting on sx.StartDate
Subscription sx
```

Observe also that if expression `L` holds the rows satisfying `templateL` and expression `R` holds the rows satisfying `templateR` then

- `L JOIN R` holds the rows satisfying `templateL AND templateR`
- `R WHERE condition` holds the rows satisfying `templateR AND condition`
- `templateR ON condition` holds the rows satisfying `templateR AND condition`

So the rows we want to SELECT from are:

```
FROM Class c
JOIN Customer c1 JOIN Customer c2
ON c1.ID <> c2.ID
JOIN Subscription s1 JOIN Subscription s2
WHERE
AND c1.ID = s1.CustomerId AND c2.ID = s2.CustomerId
AND c1.FirstName = 'Joe' AND c1.LastName = 'Bloggs'
AND c2.FirstName = 'John' AND c2.LastName = 'Snow'
AND s1.ClassId = c.ClassId AND s2.ClassId = c.ClassId
```

**Conditions can be in ANDed any order** as long as each only uses columns from a preceding JOIN or JOIN ON. So you can rearrange these in some other order if you think it better. (Eg to localize the use of some column names.) (But arguments that you *must* organize via ON (or that "," is inappropriate) are [specious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957600/3404097).)

**DISTINCT** removes duplicate rows after dropping the non-SELECTED columns from the table that the FROM etc produces. This is so that the result holds the *set* of rows that satisfy its template. DISTINCT isn't always necessary. But you still want distinct rows. In general you have to *think* about whether you can avoid DISTINCT. Sometimes you can't. Sometimes you can reason that what you do next with a table with duplicates gives the same answer whether or not there are duplicates. Rarely, the requested result is permitted to have or is supposed to have duplicates. But then you can't use that result further while reasoning via the simple relational-template expression correspondence. (Exercise: Show whether there is a SELECT returning the right classId & className values from the FROM etc table without DISTINCT.)

(It's not clear why you think that **LEFT JOIN** is appropriate. It returns what JOIN does but with unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, works like a charm and there's a lot of information here that I was unaware of before so I appreciate the tutoring. Just one quick clarification, by creating c1 and c2 (two different versions (?) of customer), is this acting as a DISTINCT in itself?

Comment: I don't know what "by creating c1 and c2 (two different versions (?) of customer), is this acting as a DISTINCT in itself" means. Please try to express it clearly. My edited answer addresses what DISTINCT does, but I don't know whether that helps you. If you want a template about c1.ID & c2.ID that says that they identify the same customer then that's c1.ID = c2.ID. Hey! We found an error in the spec. Because we want c1.ID <> c2.ID! PS The template doesn't talk about c1 & c2, because all we have is a row from pasting together a row from c1,  a row from c2, etc. c1.ID etc are its columns.

Comment: PS See also my answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35032696/3404097) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097).