# When to and when not to NATURAL JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, rdbms

I have been having this doubt for a while now, after some practices in SQL I started to ask myself: 'When is the right time to use `NATURAL JOIN`'?

Due to the enormous size of the database example that I'm using to practice my SQL skills I'm just going to put two sample queries here. Let's say I want to

> Find, for each item, the total quantity sold by the departments on the second floor

The sample answer of this question is:

```
SELECT Item.ItemName, SUM(SaleQTY)
  FROM Item INNER JOIN Sale INNER JOIN Department
  ON Item.ItemID = Sale.ItemID
  AND Department.DepartmentID = Sale.DepartmentID
  WHERE DepartmentFloor = 2
  GROUP BY Item.ItemName
  ORDER BY Item.ItemName;
```

However when doing this question myself I only used `NATURAL JOIN` and here is my attempt:

```
SELECT Item.ItemName, SUM(SaleQTY)
  FROM Item NATURAL JOIN SALE NATURAL JOIN Department
  WHERE DepartmentFloor = 2
  GROUP BY Item.ItemName
  ORDER BY Item.ItemName
```

And it produced the exact same output as the sample answer:

```
ItemName           SUM(SaleQTY)
Boots - snakeproof      2
Camel saddle            1
Elephant polo stick     1
Hat - polar explorer    3
Pith helmet             1
Pocket knife - Nile     2
Sextant                 2`
```

I understand that the reason for an `INNER JOIN` is to ensure the integrity of the data by these conditions applied in the code and eliminate any data that does not satisfy them. But still I'm wondering, is `NATURAL JOIN` sufficient enough to crack this problem?

If not, what are some important rules to follow?

Comment: I am closing this as opinion-based.  My opinion is:  *Never* use `NATURAL JOIN`.  It is a bug waiting to happen.  You want your code to be explicit about the join keys being used, so it is readable, maintainable, re-usable, and less prone to error.  `NATURAL JOIN` does not even take foreign key relationships into account.

Comment: My opinion is: *always* use `NATURAL JOIN`. Other join types produce duplicate column names (note you have redundantly used the range variable `Item.` in your second query), which is contrary to the relational model on which SQL is (loosely) based. P.S. no join type takes foreign keys into account, and nor should they.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner Join vs Natural Join vs USING clause: are there any advantages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032696/inner-join-vs-natural-join-vs-using-clause-are-there-any-advantages)

Comment: See my answer at the allegedly duplicate question. PS NATURAL JOIN is equivalent to an INNER JOIN on common columns that SELECTS only one of each.