# Natural Join in MySQL with matching columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, natural-join

What if I have two tables with primary key joins, i.e. both columns have same name and same data, and, then I have a column name timestamp, which has same name for both tables but different data according to their tables. Could I still use NATURAL JOIN? or is there a workaround considering I need to use SELECT * from both tables without aliasing?

Comment: Depends entirely on whether you need values in the timestamp columns to match. Do you?

Comment: @DourHighArch No, I the values in the timestamp will not be the same.

Comment: [Inner Join vs Natural Join vs USING clause: are there any advantages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35034568/3404097).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `NATURAL JOIN`!  It is an abomination.  It does not even take properly declared foreign key relationships into account.

You may find the `USING` clause useful:

```
select . . .
from a join
     b
     using (pk);
```

Another problem with `NATURAL JOIN` is that the join keys are not listed.  This can make it really hard to debug code, if something goes wrong.  You are experiencing the problem with the `TIMESTAMP` column.

If you do use `USING` you can use `SELECT *` and the `USING` keys appear only once in the `SELECT`.  Sometimes, this can be a convenience.

Comment: Would it give a duplicate column error if I run it as a subquery?

Comment: @Ari7 . . . Although I advise listing the columns explicitly, using `SELECT *` in a subquery can be useful.  This will not work in your case because you have the duplicate `TIMESTAMP` columns.  However, the join key will not be duplicated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Gordon Linoff. I would be needing to run something like this in a subquery, so is there a way to not encounter the duplicate column error, without aliasing. If there is some other way, it'd be great if you could direct me how to do that.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff "This will not work in your case because you have the duplicate `TIMESTAMP` columns." It's always possible to rename in a subquery `SELECT TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP2 ...` then you won't get a name clash with `NATURAL JOIN`. But better to name your columns in the base tables carefully, to avoid those clashes. Unfortunately in practice column naming is not so carefully designed, because designers don't anticipate/are prejudiced against `NATURAL JOIN`.

Comment: @AntC . . . I choose the names of my columns and tables *very* carefully after decades of experience.  Almost all my tables have columns called `createdAt`, `createdBy`, and `createdOn`, precluding the use of natural joins anyway.  That is a separate issue from the fact that they do not use properly declared foreign key relationships and they make queries more unstable and error-prone than alternatives.

Comment: So when your answer says "Don't use `NATURAL JOIN`!"; you mean: you've designed the schema/naming so that it's too hard to use; you _don't_ mean that `NATURAL JOIN` is an abomination. Yes SQL doesn't help at all with same-naming columns for a Foreign Key constraint. Sad!

Comment: @AntC . . . No, I mean it is an abomination because it does not take into account properly declared foreign key relationships.  I'm pretty sure that is what I always say, when I make that statement.

Comment: Queries don't take foreign key constraints into account *by design*.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous fixes, tha can be used in combination:

• Ensure each data element name is unqiue within its schema. For example, rather than relying on `updated_date` attribute to gain meaning via its context of appearing in the `Companies` table, instead name it `company_name_updated_date`.

• Separate entity attributes and audit attributes into distinct base tables e.g. `company_name` in the `Companies` table and `company_name_updated_date` in the CompaniesAudit table. Putting them in distinct schemas might also make sense.

• Code defensively using views: this is probably something you should be doing anyhow. Consider what attrbutes should be available to a given set of users (use cases, applications, etc), create a set of views to expose these attributes and grant privileges as required. Don't expose audit columns to users who don't need to see them.

• Code defensively in queries ('on the fly'): use drived tables to project only the columns the query requires, therefore if a new column is added to an existing then it isn't a 'breaking change' for that query. Exmaple:

```
WITH c AS ( SELECT company_id, company_name FROM Companies ),
p AS ( SELECT employee_id, company_name FROM Payroll )
SELECT * FROM c NATURAL JOIN p;
```